# Can Asana API upload an attachment to a task

Tags: asana

I would like to programmatically upload an attachment to a task in Asana. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at this time, but we'll make sure it's on our list of feature requests.

Comment: Afraid not. And we have a few key features on the development priority list before this one, so I expect you'll have to wait a little while longer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908100/http-post-multipart-form-data-upload-file-using-java-on-the-asana-api/29908101#29908101

Answer (score 4):

While Greg was correct at the time he wrote this, I'm now pleased to say you can both fetch and upload attachments via the API: https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/attachments

Answer (score 0):

Actually Asana Api supports attachments uploads, but I didn't work from java. I'm using multipart/form-data with a Custom MultipartRequest class that works in other rest implementations, but nothing in the Asana doc is clear to know what headers/params we need to implement in the request to works properly, I'm getting BadRequestError all the time. Anybody knows anything about that?

Comment: You may want to check out this answer to help you. If you are having further trouble please ask a question on here and make sure to tag it with the asana tag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908100/http-post-multipart-form-data-upload-file-using-java-on-the-asana-api/29908101#29908101